# Discrepancy in daily rep score between PSE and SE weekly league

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I earned 60 rep on PSE yesterday, as shown on [my rep page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/recent/14221?StartDate=2011-02-27&EndDate=2011-02-27):

[image]

However, in the [weekly user league](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/52/week/programmers) only 30 points appear:

[image]

I suspect this is a side effect of yesterday's rep recalc, where I lost exactly 30 points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a temporary issue resulting from the global rep recalc.  It has since been resolved. (:

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the reputation league figure is fairly heavily cached and only updated once or twice a day, whereas your profile page figure is "real time".

Comment: Yes, but it is (or should be) updated at the end of the day.